# Creating a grocery list via string inputs and void functions - Input string does not display

Tags: c

I'm fairly new to C (high school student), and my goal is to make a grocery list by inputting a set of characters. Then, the output would print out what I currently added to the list. This would go on forever until I exited the program or went to the main menu.

**SCREEN1**

```
 00 - GO TO GREETINGS SCREEN
 01 - ADD MORE ITEMS TO THE LIST

 CODE ENTRY: ___
```

**SCREEN2**

Then I entered 01 to add items:

```
 Input "DONE" to end program and see final list.

 LIST ENTRY: ______________
```

**SCREEN3**

Then I add "apples", then it takes me to this screen:

```
 GROCERY LIST:
 POTATOES
 FISH
 APPLES
```

After that, it takes me back to SCREEN1, where I would choose whether to go to the greetings screen or add some more.

**MY CURRENT CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    char * grocery;
    mainMenu:
    system("cls");
    n = 0;
    printf("00 - Go to greetings screen\n01 - Add groceries to list\nENTRY: ");scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n == 0)
    {
        greetings();
        goto mainMenu;
    }
    else if(n == 1)
    {
        printf("GROCERY ENTRY: ");scanf("%s",grocery);
        add(grocery);
        goto mainMenu;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong value added. Try again.");
        sleep(2);
        goto mainMenu;
    }
}

void greetings()
{
    system("cls");
    printf("hello! press any key to go back to menu");
    getch();
    system("cls");
}

void add(char * a)
{
    system("cls");
    char listData[1000] = "",slashN[4] = "\n";
    strcat(listData,a);
    strcat(listData,slashN);
    printf("THINGS TO BUY:\n");
    puts(listData);
}
```

**NOTES**

I used strcat so that it remembers the value of the original string. This'll make sure that the new input will just be put on top of the old data, right? (*Hopefully, my logic is correct on that one*)

Though, I have not been able to find out whether or not the string data will still be remembered by the program even if I am switching to other menus, such as the Greetings Menu (*which is a placeholder for something like a calculator*).

Right now, the initial functions work, except for the the grocery list one. Whenever I input a string, nothing comes out of it, even the `printf("THINGS TO BUY:")` part, leading me to think it's something with what I entered in `void add(char * a)`

Comment: scanf() does not allocate any space for 'strings', (NUL-terminated char arrays), that it loads.  You must do that before loading, say, '*grocery'.  A local in a function like 'add' will not do - its lifetime does not exceed the function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying out your code, I received a segmentation fault where you have `scanf("%s",grocery);`. Try allocating space to the variable, using malloc(3) (see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html). For example, `char *grocery = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);` will give you 100 characters to read into your grocery variable from input.

The same objective can also be achieved by simply using `char grocery[100];` as you have with other variables.

Furthermore, as many programmers would suggest, try not to use `goto()`. This can cause spaghetti code (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code). Instead, use a while loop that stops only when the user inputs some action designed to stop entering requests.

Lastly, just so you avoid unwarranted results, `\n` is actually a single character. Therefore, `char slashN[4] = "\n"` can be `char slashN = '\n';`.

Happy coding! :D